# how to set 2 div overlap and hide each other on click

Tags: html

I want to set 1 div on another div , on click  i want to show 1 div and hide another,

how could i do that?

```
<div id="div1">
            <ul>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="div2">
            <ul>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
                <li>Item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: like so `#div2 { display: none; }`? onclick you just hide `div1` and show `div2`. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XawkP/)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the DIV using it's style.display attribute:

```
div1.style.display='none';  //will hide the div
div1.style.display='';      //will show the div
```